# Proof that the Kruskal-Szekeres extension is maximal

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems, resource-recommendations

I am trying to find a rigorous proof that the Kruskal-Szekeres extension is maximal. The Kruskal-Szekeres extension of the well-known Schwarzschild solution is given by the Lorentzian manifold $(M_{KS}, g_{KS})$ where $M_{KS} := \{ (T,X) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | T^2 - X^2 < 1 \} \times S^2$, with $S^2$ being the unit two-sphere and metric $g$ given by $$g_{KS} = \frac{32m^3}{r}e^{-r/2m}\left(-dT^2 + dX^2\right) + r^2d\Omega^2 ,$$ where $r$ is regarded as a function of $(T,X)$. It is an extension of Schwarzschilds solution in the sense that the manifold in Schwarzschild-coordinates $(t,r,\theta, \phi)$, namely $M_S := \mathbb{R} \times (2m, \infty) \times S^2$ can be isometrically embedded into $M_{KS}$ in a proper manner, meaning the image of the embedding is not $M_{KS}$. From what I have read, e.g. in Chruściels "Black Holes", a spacetime $(M, g)$ is called $(C^k-)$maximal or $(C^k-)$inextendible, if no $(C^k-)$extension exists (the definition of an extension here includes that it has to be a proper embedding).

My question is: Is there a rigorous proof of the inextendibility of $(M_{KS}, g_{KS})$ that can be found somewhere in the literature?

In his original paper, Kruskal briefly argues that every geodesic is either complete (if it is defined for all values of an affine parameter) or runs into the singularity at $r=0$, given by the  locus of $T^2-X^2 = 1$. The best I could find in the literature was a paper by Chruściel and Cortier, regarding the "Maximal analytic extension of the Emparan-Reall black ring", where they rigorously proved that the created extension is maximal. The main part of that proof is the examination of the geodesic segments by looking at the first integrals and constants of motion, and deriving that they are either complete or run into the singularity. They state that the same can be done for the Kruskal-Szekeres extension, it would be even easier as the geodesics could be analyzed in a simpler manner, but they did not do it.
I tried it myself by looking at the first integrals for a general geodesic $\gamma(s) = (t(s), r(s), \theta(s), \phi(s))$ in Schwarzschild coordinates,  $$\frac{dt}{ds} = E\left(1-\frac{2m}{r}\right)^{-1} \qquad \frac{d\phi}{ds} = \frac{L}{r^2} \qquad \frac{d\theta}{ds} = 0 \qquad \left(\frac{dr}{ds}\right)^2 = E^2 - \left(\lambda + \frac{L^2}{r^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{2m}{r}\right), $$ where $\lambda = 1$ is for timelike, $\lambda = 0$ for null and $\lambda = -1$ for spacelike geodesics (see Chruściels book "Elements of GR").

My problem now is, how to proceed? From what I understood of the proof in the aforementioned paper, among other things I have to show that all components of $\dot{\gamma}$ are bounded. How do I do this in the several regions of the Kruskal-Szekeres chart and what else do I need to show that the geodesics are either complete or run into $r = 0$? Is there some reference to literature or papers where this has been done?